Converting $x^3$ Optimization to an Equivalent LP Problem
Suppose we want to find the minimum of a a strictly increasing function $f: [-a, a] \to \mathbb{R} $, for some $a > 0$, which is also concave in $[-a, 0]$ and convex in $[0, a]$ (exactly like the $x^3$ mentioned in the title).
Is it possible to convert this optimization problem into an equivalent LP, using a PWL approximation of $f$? I know this would have been possible had $f$ been convex everywhere, but I am struggling to see whether this is also doable.
P.S.: The obvious answer is that its minimum should always be at $-a$ since $f$ is increasing, but there might be other constraints to be met as well that will impact the optimal solution.

I've only seen the statement that you can turn a convex optimization problem into an optimization problem with linear objective function and convex constraints (see link). Is this what you meant?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585729/convert-any-convex-optimization-problem-to-a-linear-objective

@Sudix Indeed, that is true. But in my case the function is not convex; it is concave in $[-a, 0]$ and convex in $[0, a]$ and strictly increasing everywhere. It seems to have a lot of “good” properties to not be convertible to a LP.

The key detail is that we more or less just hide all cumbersome details of the objective function into the constraints in the method I linked. If you want to get a LP, then this poses a way stronger restriction on the constraints.  So, the method of the link doesn't work anymore, even if $f$ is convex everywhere.

@Sudix For convex function there is a conversion to LP using the epigraph of $f$ in the inequality constraints. I’m not sure if we could the same for this case too, by splitting it into two parts, one $< 0$ and one $> 0$, maybe introducing a binary variable to model the mutual exclusivity of these subsets.

That's no conversion to LP. It's a problem with linear objective, and convex constraints. LP means linear objective and linear constraints.

@Sudix If you approximate your non-linear function with a PWL one, then you have your LP - sorry for the confusion, you are right, should have mentioned that, too, otherwise it’s not a LP. I updated the post as well.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/12282/special-case-of-minimum-cost-flow-problem-with-variable-cost
